# Select statement with Condition and SSRS parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a situation with a query as follows.

In SSRS I have a @Parameter called Block, with values as follows: Block A, Block B, and Block C. User would select Date range and then Block Value.

The output is essentially a qualification system that shows names:
The Primary Query is as follows:

```
Select EmpName, EmpID from EmpDtls where EmpassignID in (@Block)
```

Now what I want to do is as follows:

When User selects a Block: the query should validate the Parameter based on Query. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
select Case
when (@Block) = A then (select Personnel_level from Block where PersnelQual = 'A', 'B')
when (@block) = C then (select Personnel_level from Block where PersnelQual = 'B', 'C')
END
from PersnelQual
```

So when the user runs the report with the following parameters:

Start Date: 05/01/2021
End Date: 05/07/2021
Block: A

The output should be something like this

| Emp Name | Emp Id |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | 123 |
| Mary | 456 |

Is this possible?

Comment: `@Block` is what? A comma-separated `varchar`? Then you need to split the string, which version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 0):

No `case` is needed.  Just put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select Personnel_level
from Block
where (@Block = A and PersnelQual in ('A', 'B')) or
      (@block = C and PersnelQual in ('B', 'C'));
```